# How do I assign a value to a variable from a method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, random

This is my first question. Upon programming in Java, I ran into an error. I am trying to assign a random integer value to the variable myRand. But, I have a method to do it (The method to do this is called getRandom). Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame 
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int getRandom()
 {
    int doubleRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 51);
    return doubleRandom;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    double myRand;
    getRandom(myRand);
 }
}
```

Here is the error message it game me (sorry I forgot):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method getRandom() in the type GuessingGame is not applicable for the arguments     (double)

at GuessingGame.main(GuessingGame.java:16)
```

It has an error at line 16. Can anyone help? (By the way, I am making this into a guessing game program.)

Comment: Read and listen to the error message. It will say something about not being able to find a method with the given signature: so what *is* the signature - what arguments it takes and what it returns - of `getRandom` and how is it being called? There is a mismatch in how it is defined and how it is used.

Comment: *"By the way, I am making this into a guessing game program."* - Ironically, you have also turned this into guessing game for people to answer.  Tell us what the error message says.  Don't force us to guess.

Comment: The absolute worst thing you can say on Stack Overflow is "It had an error. Please help." ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS tell us the EXACT error message you are given, even if it makes no sense to you. Give us the full stack trace (the stuff Java dumps to the console if you get an error) or the build error (what the compiler gives you). Also, tell us if the program doesn't compile (syntax error) or crashes at runtime (runtime error).

Comment: Also, user2246674 is correct--you are defining a method, but using it differently than how you define it. Look and see if you can find a `getRandom(double)` method. Also, you can't assign a value to a primitive type from a method--primitives are passed by value; the program simply copies myRand, and changes the method makes won't be reflected in the method. But first, look at the difference between line 16 and line 7. That is where your problem lies. None of us can answer your question until you tell us your exact error, both because we need it to respond and because your question is on hold.

Answer (score 0):

your method signature does not allow any arguments and you are passing a double type parameter to the same thats why the code is failing